# bootstrap 5 hide collapsed navbar on link click

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I want to know how to hide the navbar after clicking a link.
this is HTML code

```
<header class="header-nav" id="home">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg custom-nav fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a id="brand" href="#">
        <span>C</span> Solutions
      </a>
      <button
        class="navbtn"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span>
          <i class="fas fa-bars burger-menu"></i>
        </span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 text-center">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#home">
              Home
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              about us
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#services">
              services
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              why choose us
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              careers
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              portfolio
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#our-clients">
              our clients
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">
              contact us
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <button class="btn btn-primary">request a quote</button>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

I already used the javascript method after answering the same question here before, but it is not working.

```
const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-item')
const menuToggle = document.getElementById('navbarSupportedContent')
const bsCollapse = new bootstrap.Collapse(menuToggle)
navLinks.forEach((l) => {
    l.addEventListener('click', () => { bsCollapse.toggle() })
})
```

I also tried the bootstrap way to Use the data-bs-toggle and data-bs-target data attributes in the markup on each link to toggle the Collapse navbar, but what happened is when clicking on a link it closes the navbar but does not go to the section clicked.
can anyone help?

Comment: Can you try removing the href from the <li> and in your event listener after the bsCollapse.toggle() navigate to the href manually. You'll just have to tell your event listener which href to go to based on which link is being clicked.